# How to clean up date field values migrated from old Sitecore versions

Tags: migration, serialization

After migrating content from Sitecore 6.5 I see dates staying not in canonical 8+ Sitecore format.

Some samples (raw values) from my current project:

- `20140329T120917` - no `Z` at the end
- `20140329T123823:635316935030258782` - no need for so many digits

All dates created in Sitecore 8 (I checked `Created` and `Updated` fields) follow the same `yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ` pattern.

What is the best way to change dates format when content is moved from old Sitecore version to a new one?

Comment: If I were at a computer I would totally show you a solution in SPE. Unfortunately I'm sitting in a parking lot. I can however tell you that we use SPE to serialize SPE items while removing the Z. Will try to point you to the script that makes the magic happen.

Comment: We have a function here to fix legacy dates.https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Cognifide.PowerShell/Data/serialization/master/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script%20Library/Platform/Development/PowerShell%20Extensions%20Maintenance/Serialize%20Changes.item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a prototype for you to test with in your non-production instance.

**Sitecore PowerShell Extensions**

```powershell
$items = @(Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home") + @(Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\content\home")
$expression = "\d{8}[T]\d{6}"
foreach($item in $items) {
    $item.BeginEdit() | Out-Null
    if($item.Fields["__Created"].HasValue -and ($item.Fields["__Created"].Value -match $expression)) {
        $item.Fields["__Created"].Value = $matches[0]
    }

    if($item.Fields["__Updated"].HasValue -and ($item.Fields["__Updated"].Value -match $expression)) {
        $item.Fields["__Updated"].Value = $matches[0]
    }
    $item.EndEdit() | Out-Null
}
```

The code finds the home item and the immediate children, then looks for dates that have values and matches the pattern you specified. I'm accessing the value directly on the field since it gives the raw value (rather than a datetime).

Answer (score 2):

PSE sounds like a goer, though if you're not comfortable with PowerShell and as it's a migration project which you're going to re-run then you could do something with the rules engine.

On the 8.x instance when the content item from 6.x saves, have a rule which examine the date fields and change as appropriate.

Can only find an old cookbook (https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/61/rules_engine_cookbook_sc61_a4.pdf)  on the rules engine as I'm on a train with a dodgy web connection

Comment: Note that at least the current version of Sitecore 8 will automatically update date fields from the old format to the new.